# Why just looping the last input?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, matrix, nested-loops

so I wanna make a program to find each sum of the columns of a matrix. In this code first you can input how many matrix you want and the second input is the size of matrix (n x n) and third input is the value of matrix.

The output must be each sum of the columns of matrix

here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int x, y, z;
    int inp1, inp2;
    int matrix[100][100];
    int matrix2;
    
    scanf("%d", &inp1);
    
    for(z = 0; z < inp1; z++){
        scanf("%d", &inp2);
        for(x = 0; x < inp2; x++){
            for(y = 0; y < inp2; y++){
                scanf("%d", &matrix[x][y]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(z = 0; z < inp1; z++){
        printf("Case #%d:", z+1);
        for(x = 0; x < inp2; x++){
            matrix2 = 0;
            for(y = 0; y < inp2; y++){
                matrix2 += matrix[y][x];
                if(y == inp2-1){
                    printf(" %d", matrix2);
                } 
            }
        }
        printf("\n");   
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

here's the input and ouput for that code

```
2 //first input (how many matrix)
2 //second input (size of matrix)
1 2 //third input (matrix)
1 2
3
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 4 5
Case #1: 6 7 8
Case #2: 6 7 8
```

for the second output is correct but the first output is wrong.
output for the second one from 1+2+3 = 6, 1+2+4 = 7, 1+2+5 = 8

What I want is the output for the first case is 2 and 4

Comment: `matrix2[x]` where `matrix2` is an `int` is not valid. Didn't your compiler give you an error for that?

Comment: You need to read one matrix, do the operation on it, and output the results, then read the next matrix, and so on. You need to restructure your loops a bit. Right now it looks like you read the first matrix then immediately overwrite the data with the next, then perform the operation.

Comment: ahhh i forgot to delete the [x] i wrong cooppied before

Comment: I tried to make a code to input first then directly output but its more complicated than this haha. How can the code still like this (input first then output) but can read the first matrix and doesn't overwrite the data with the next. I'm bad at looping XD

Comment: Following @RetiredNinja: This results in merging the two `for(z)` loops into one: `for(z) { for(x) { for(y) { ... } } /* } for(z) { */ for(x) { for(y) { ... } } }`

Comment: Side note: Within the second inner-most `for(y)` loop: `if(y == inp2 - 1) { ... }` – this condition will be true on very last loop run only, and as this is the last thing you do within the loop, this will only occur at the very end – so better move that *behind* the loop, printing unconditionally: `for(y) { ... } printf(...);` – does the same, is easier to read and more efficient for not checking the condition with *every* loop run.

Comment: @Aconcagua for if(y == inp2 - 1) { ... } i did it on purpose because i just wanted to display the sum result for each columns

Comment: You still do so if you print it *after* the `for(y)` loop *but still within* the `for(x)` loop!